# How i should change this log4js

Tags: javascript, node.js, log4js-node

How i should change this :

```
log4js.configure({
    appenders: [
        { type: 'console' },
        { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site.log' }
    ]
});
```

---

Because i get this  error that:

```
Error: Problem with log4js configuration: ({ appenders:
   [ { type: 'console' },
     { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site.log' } ] }) - must have a property "appenders" of type object.
```

Comment: The error description seems enough. "appenders" is an object and not an array.

Answer (score 0):

`appenders` should be a plain object, providing each appender as a value for a given name (the key):

```
log4js.configure({
    appenders: {
        con: { type: 'console' },
        fil: { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site.log' }
    }
});
```

An appender is then referenced by name, like so:

```
log4js.getLogger('con');
```

See also the [documentation](https://nomiddlename.github.io/log4js-node/appenders.html).